# How to add multiple colors to border

Tags: css

I would like to have three colors on my border-bottom like in the image below. How can I achieve this affect?

[image]

Comment: He was not using borders, I guess it's just a transparent background. Using CSS would be much more difficult since you have to divide the container into three smaller

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an `:after` pseudo-element with a `linear-gradient`:

```css
body {
  background: #e4e4e4;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.box:after {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #bcbcbc 25%,
    #ffcd02 25%,
    #ffcd02 50%,
    #e84f47 50%,
    #e84f47 75%,
    #65c1ac 75%
  );
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    It Can be easily achieved with 3 div help
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.container{
display:flex;
}
#div1 {

  border-bottom-left-radius:50px ;
  height:15px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#49783f;
}

#div2 {
height:15px;
  background-color:#682a30;
width:150px;
}
#div3 {
height:15px;
width:200px;
background-color:#bdbdbe;
border-bottom-right-radius:50px ;
}
</
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code.

```
.custom-box{
width: 100px;
height:3rem;
background: rgba(126, 126,126, 0.4);
position: relative;
border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.custom-box:before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
inset:100% 0 0 0;
margin-bottom: -6px;
border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
background: linear-gradient(
to right,
green 40%,
red 40%,
red 60%,
gray 60%);
}
```

```
<div class="custom-box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [border images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image). They're widely supported in most browsers and are easy to use. Here's how you can use border images to create this effect:

1. Use Figma to design the border you want and then export it as an SVG. (If you're not sure how to export here's a [good article](https://designcode.io/figma-handbook-export-svg) that should help you.)
2. Add the SVG to your project
3. Import it like so `border-image: url("/somepath/border.svg")`